# PNG not showing in ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a large .png and i want to show it in a Splash screen, but the image is not showing. The xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.infaplic.lpi.activities.SplashActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"/>
```

And the code of the Activity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

ImageView imagen;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    imagen=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imagen.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pantalla_arranque));
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            SplashActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
}
```

This way, the image is not showing. I have tried with android:src: in the xml, but it doesn't work.

The image is very large. Do I need to resize it before putting it in the ImageView? If not, why is the image not showing?

Thank you.

EDIT: The PNG is 1080x1920

Comment: Quick question, is there any other XML element in that file?

Comment: No, the XML is exactly as I show here.

Comment: Check the logs, once I was trying to add a very long png, about 4000 px in height. The imagview can't just fit this size. So if your image is very large it wont be shown on the screen, but some warning in logs should be written.

Comment: Have you tried to delay your sleep?

Comment: @rekire I see, just wanted him to check logs. Because he should probably get the warning if it's too big =)

Comment: Not getting warnings for too big image

Comment: I asked the photoshop guy to send me images a bit smaller, lets see

Comment: Its an image size problem...The image is now 551x980 and it is shown. Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you write that your image is very large I would guess it is too large. I have a bug in one of my apps there I generate an image which is bigger then 2048 pixels. Some devices does not support such big images I would guess that you run into a similar problem.

If that is some background image reduce the image size, a background image is not so important that each pixel on the screen has to own a image pixel.

Answer (score 18):

In my case I was using a image with file name like "go-back-filename.png". And xml file is like

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/go-back-icon"/>
```

After i changed the file name to "go_back_icon" it worked fine.
Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This was really helpful. Small miss that I was reminded by this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Add Below this. Please read  Options for scaling the bounds of an image to the bounds of this [view.ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) in your ImageView

### Use This

```
imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.pantalla_arranque);
```

Then

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

**`android:adjustViewBounds`** : Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.

Must be a `boolean` value, either "true" or "false".
Please Check demo  [ImageView scaleType Samples](http://etcodehome.blogspot.in/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html) . I hope it helps you

Comment: I think your ImageSize too big ,Check my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Change your `ImageView` to this :

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/imageView2"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:adjustViewBounds="false"/>
```

If it's not working try to add this on your `manifest` (inside your `Activity)` `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`

### EDIT

I was looking for the answer, but I thought that better try it by my self... and I've created a sample project where I use an `ImageView` 1080x1920 and I was testing since I've found that I've I put 3000 miliseconds it shows up... wiht 1000 miliseconds won't show up if you don't rescale it.

By the way `getDrawable()` is deprecated I recomend to you use :

```
imagen.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.imagenprueva));
```

XML

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@drawable/imagen"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the full source code hope it helps [Source code](http://paste.ofcode.org/ypvY6nCmcEmrnUjhANmnCJ)

Comment: @Fustigador Also I've tried to instead of doing the setImageDrawable programmatically trying to put it on XML src is slower than Background... I mean if you put Background it will show the Image more time ( I'm testing with 3 seconds ) btw I'm using this [Image](http://samsung-wallpapers.com/uploads/allimg/130526/1-130526201224.jpg) what image are you trying to use?

Comment: Im using a PNG that our photoshop guy sent to me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87362/discussion-between-skizo-and-fustigador).

Answer (score 0):

In your .xml file
add
`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

then in the ImageView add this line of code:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/books"
```

NOT

`tools:srcCompat="@drawable/books"`